# How do I solve $ \int \frac{t+1}{dt}=\int\frac{-y^2}{dy} $?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

How can I integrate the following:
$$
\int  \frac{t+1}{dt}=\int\frac{-y^2}{dy}
$$

would I integrate normally and inverse it? like: $$\int\frac{1}{dy} = \frac{1}{y} + c $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you do it ? You don't. :-) If your differential equation is $\dfrac{t+1}{dt}=\dfrac{-y^2}{dy}$ , then reverse the two fractions, and integrate after. You'll get $\ln(t+1)=\dfrac1y$ .